# In Ecto when should I use assoc_constraint vs foreign_key_constraint

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I know the difference between the two; `assoc_constraint` uses the ecto schema to validate the foreign key constraint, `foreign_key_constraint` uses the db.

Why would you ever use `assoc_constraint` in that case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the source of [`assoc_constraint`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.9.4/lib/ecto/changeset.ex#L2915) and [`foreign_key_constraint`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.9.4/lib/ecto/changeset.ex#L2861), you'll see that they end with very similar call to `add_constraint` (private function)

assoc_constraint:

```
add_constraint(changeset, :foreign_key, to_string(constraint),
               :exact, assoc, {message, []})
```

foreign_key_constraint:

```
add_constraint(changeset, :foreign_key, to_string(constraint),
               :exact, field, {message, []})
```

The only difference between the two is, for `foreign_key_constraint` you give the exact name of the constraint, and for `assoc_constraint`, you give the name of the association and the function computes the foreign key name itself (using the same convention as Ecto migrations). Other than that, both work identically. `assoc_constraint` is just a convenience function so you don't have to use the exact name of the constraint, which is longer than the association name.

Comment: you are like the John Skeet of Elixir @Dogbert